# Using SSL\TLS for free in a public program

Tags: client-server, ssl

I really need to use SSL in my Socket Server\Client Communication but paying for a certification is too over priced for me :( i can't afford payed Certification

[Note] : my program will be publicly released so i wanna to secure my program communication with my server

The Question Is : Is it possible to use SSL\TLS for free in an effective [Without Security Riscs] way because i can't afford payed certificates... ?

Comment: A domain validated certificate is only $35. Surely you have that right?

Comment: what i want is a certification to encrypt my Socket Server and client communication

Comment: Doesn't answer the comment. You will spend far more than $35 getting it working, and supporting it, and fielding user problems, without a CA certificate than with one. Spend the thirty-five bucks.

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean ? A self-signed certificate did not differ from the CA one except with the trusted for all browsers.
Also can you tell me which website i could get this 35 cert ?

Comment: I've already told you what I mean. What part of it didn't you understand?

Comment: Doesn't answer the comment. You will spend far more than $35 getting it working, and supporting it, and fielding user problems, without a CA certificate than with one. Spend the thirty-five bucks.

Comment: this one what you mean by that i will spend far more that 35$ to get my Self-signed certificate working ? also fielding user problem, which probs ???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags stand alone.  That is, selecting `client`, `server` and `communication` does not mean that you're actually talking about client-server communication.  Please select tags with care.

Comment: Just repeating my own words back to me just wastes time and space. If you have a specific question, ask it. But if you haven't priced a proper SSL certificate you haven't done enough research to be asking this question yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use SSL\TLS for free in an effective way because i
>   can't afford payed certificates... ?

Yes it is. Buying certificates from a trusted CA, makes your server be trusted by **all** browsers without any manual action (e.g. Verisign).
If you own both the client and server and you are using SSL you can create your own certificates (or get free ones) and *install* them to all clients as trusted (in an off-line process).
The only part that relates to security now is the key size. Should be at least 2048 bits.
But there is one catch. If you create your own certificates you need to be careful what extensions you set so that you don't have any issues during deployment. The CAs know how to create `X509v3` compliant certificates to be accepted by all browser (libraries) without any issues

Comment: So your comment make me want to ask some more questions. 
1- What do you mean by offline process ? must all clients disconnect their internet connection to install my program.

2- What do you mean by the extensions part ? what i do is creating a .pfx file then install it to my pc and export it again to be used in program

Comment: 1)I mean you will have to go manually to install the truststore.2)I mean `X509v3` extensions

Comment: I am creating a 2048 bits certification using C# and saved as .pfx then i install it to my certification store then export it as a .cer to use it to my application...

Comment: Also is there a risk if Enable exportable private key ? is enabled ?

Comment: Also if i created my self-signed certificate in a good way, is there a security risk in having a self signed certificate [if well created 2048++ bits]?

Comment: @TorlanOther:The security risk here, is the part where **you** install the certificate to your clients.Also issue it to **your** domain (not localhost or some fake name).If you have a domain name...

Comment: @TorlanOther:Also the key assumption here is that **you** control the clients

Comment: you mean the cn=localhost right ? i will make it my domain name when i get one www.mydomain.com and the clients will have to remain connected to my server in order for the program to work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: What you're buying from a CA (certificate authority) is typically NOT a certificate. Typically, you create your own certificate, and ask the CA for a "signature", which you present to the client (browser, etc) in order to show that your certificate is trusted by that CA.

Browsers (and other software) typically have a internal list of CAs they trust. This is why one generally buys a signature - to have one's certificate recognized as valid by currently deployed software. 
However, you are not required to get such a signature. You can just as well create your certificate (typically referred to as a "self signed" certificate) and either ask the end-user to introduce it to the software as trusted, or distribute it included in the software itself.

There are [lots](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) [of](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate.html) [instructions](http://www.dylanbeattie.net/docs/openssl_iis_ssl_howto.html) on how to create a self-signed certificate on the web, typicaly using the openSSL CLI, but also IIS, or Java.

As to how you deploy such a certificate on your software, you're better of asking another question.

Comment: i am creating my self-signed certificates using c# Pluralsight's certification manager but there is a bug in this program that Enable exportable private key is always ENABLED so is there a risk in that ?

Comment: Also if i created my self-signed certificate in a good way, is there any difference between it and the CA one other that it is trusted by all browsers ? is there a security risk in having a self signed certificate ?

Comment: @TorlanOther you definitely DO NOT want to export your private key along with the certificates you distribute to the public. It TOTALLY destroys any kind of security your system could possibly have. If the operation is done correctly, there's absolutely no difference between a self-signed certificate and a CA-signed one, other than convenience. I strongly advise you to use OpenSSL instead of other (possibly shady) implementation to create the certificates.

Comment: @TorlanOther Also, from your questions, you'd benefit from reading the [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_cryptography) and [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) articles on wikipedia.

Comment: What made me think of SSL is the worry of MITM attack so with alot of reading on the internet i have found that maybe SSL is the less vulnerable to MITM attack and it is best security to be used in a client server communication so is this true ?

Comment: @TorlanOther Indeed. Using SSL, the MITM threat is eliminated (if you keep your certificates private and there's no breakthrough on number factoring). Also, you cease being vulnerable to passive sniffing (of passwords, for example)